# jde-import-all doesn't see playframework(play.mvc.*) classes

Tags: java, emacs, playframework, classpath, jde

I'd like to use emacs(with jde) for playframework java coding. 
(setting up jde alone is a big trouble but it's done)

For a start, I'm trying to use M-x jde-import-all to import all classes.
It runs but fails to import(or list) play.mvc.* classes.

I tried setting (jde-set-variables '(jde-global-classpath ( quote ("~/../myApp/conf" "~/play/framework" ~/play/framework/lib") )))
but no avail.

Comment: @wvxvw: oh are there newer java mode for emacs then?